# New Tags for common descriptions needed?

Tags: discussion

When reading throught the Qs, I often read about `custom taxonomies` & `custom post types` that contain the following "names":

- [employee](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/employee)
- [position](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/position)
- [real-estate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate)
- [event](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/event)

We could probably avoid a lot of these Qs, with adding some tags as the tasks are nearly the same.

Comment: @kasier Ah ok. I misunderstood your question. Now it's clear. Thanks. Deleting comment.

Comment: @Maugly Edited the Q.

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to delete comments - they can help provide context for other people viewing the question.

Comment: @tnorthcut As long as i was just to clarify the Q (which is updated now, thanks to the comment) it's ok for me. Readers should imho only get the relevant part and others should try to avoid the noise. It's about saving your time :)